# apache2 no listening sockets available, but nothing listening on the port

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl, apache-virtualhost

I'm trying to setup SSL on an ubuntu server. I've generated a key and certificate with the following commands `openssl genrsa -out mydomain.key 1024` and `openssl req -new -key mydomain.key -x509 -out mydomain.crt`. I added `LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so` to httpd.conf, and the relevant(I think) excerpt from my httpd.conf is

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 80
Listen 443
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
ProxyPass /software-suite http://localhost:8087/software-suite
ProxyPassReverse /software-suite http://localhost:8087/software-suite

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/hostname.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/hostname.key
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPass /software-suite http://localhost:8087/software-suite
ProxyPassReverse /software-suite http://localhost:8087/software-suite

</VirtualHost>
```

When I run `sudo service apache2 start`, I get

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                           Thu Feb 25 23:01:37 2016] [warn] module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu Feb 25 23:01:37 2016] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf at line 499 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

but when I run `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':443'` nothing is listening

**Update**

I moved the `<VirtualHost *:443>` node and its contents to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`.  When I start apache2 I get

```
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                                               [Fri Feb 26 16:36:43 2016] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf at line 499 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ]
```

and I can now access my website on port 80 but I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when I try to access it with https.  Also when I execute `sudo service apache2 status` I get `Apache2 is NOT running.` even though it appears to be handling requests coming into port 80. I also commented out `NameVirtualHost *:443`, `LoadModule ssl_module`, and `Listen 443` in `httpd.conf`.  I don't see any errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/access.log`, the only logs in `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: What version of apache do you have? execute `apache2 -v`. What version of ubuntu you have? execute `lsb_release -a`. Did you manually create the `httpd.conf file`?

Comment: Apache version is Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu).  Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.  I did not manually create the httpd.conf file

Comment: Try setting the configuration only in the SSL virtual hosts file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`). Make a copy of the current httpd file and/or rename it. Give a try

Comment: NameVirtualHost  is obsolete now, no so sure about 2.2.x; what happens when you comment out the two NameVirtualHost lines, and add a Listen 80 before the Listen 443 line?

Comment: I tried your suggestion @RuiFRibeiro with no luck.  With your suggestion @tachomi I can access the website on port 80 but when I try https I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.  I'll update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58650/what-steps-are-required-to-enable-ssl-on-apache2-with-ubuntu.  I had to execute `sudo a2ensite default-ssl` and restart apache2.